# susy, media queries, and lt IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media, susy-compass

I was wondering what (if any) shims you use to get the magic grids to respond correctly in [SUSY](http://susy.oddbird.net/) in IE8 and under?

On non-susy sites I've always used [moderizr](http://modernizr.com/) or the shim from google and they worked as expected. I'm working on my first SUSY site and the media queries for the largest size won't kick in.

http://dev.apehangar.com

Comment: Personally, I use a solution based on this concept:  http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/

Comment: Thank you cimmanon. I also just tried respond.js and it does the trick too. Still have to work on a couple ie only % widths on a few containers, but it as that shouldn't be too hard. But again, thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me what sort of "shim" you are looking for. I don't know any good way to make MQs work in IE8, but Susy does have an option to [output styles under a fallback class](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-media-layouts). Those styles wont respond dynamically, but you can use it to send IE a desktop site:

```
.page {
  width: 20em;
  @include at-breakpoint(30em 12 no-mediaqueries) {
    width: 70em;
  }
}
```

Will output:

```
.page { width: 20em; }
@media (min-width: 30em) { .page { width: 70em; } }
.no-mediaqueries .page { width: 70em; }
```

You can replace "no-mediaqueries" with any fallback class you want. Just make sure that class is applied using Modernizr or IE conditional comments.

Comment: oh, I did not know about the no-mediaqueries. So for instance, if I am working mobile size up to desktop, at my break-points i could add the no-mediaqueries and set my .page width to my large (desktop) size? Is that how you would do it?

Comment: Simply add the "no-mediaqueries" fallback to any breakpoint that you want read by IE8. If you use variables for your breakpoints (e.g. `$desktop: 70em 12;`) you can add the fallback class there, and it will be used in all your `$desktop` breakpoints.