# At-breakpoint fallback causes error

Tags: internet-explorer, susy-compass, fallback

I found the topic [susy, media queries, and lt IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899945/susy-media-queries-and-lt-ie9/12925160#12925160) where it's stated you can add the "fallback class" to the variable as to have it applied at all the specified at-breakpoints that use the variable.

So I changed my variable:

```
    $desk: 58em 12;
```

to

```
    $desk: 58em 12 lt-ie9;
```

But this causes an error like this:

```
    Syntax error: Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-se1ector-referencing character ' & ' .
    on line 91 of C: /Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_media.scss,         in ‘ Gcontent '
    from line 15 of C: /Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_media.scss, in ‘ layout '
    from line 54 of C: /Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_media.scss, in ‘ at-breakpoint '
    from line 87 of C: /localpath/sass/layouts/project/site.layout.scss
```

The last line is the first line where the media-layout varible "$desk" is called for the first time.

```
    @include at-breakpoint($desk) {
    .l-header,
    .l-main,
    .l-footer,
    .l-region--navigation {
      @include set-container-width; // Reset only the container width (elements have already been declared as containers).
    }
```

Am I missing some obvious syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Sass issue, and should be fixed in Sass 3.3 (currently in alpha). In order to set a fallback class, Susy has to use the Sass parent selector (`&`) — but that selector fails when there is no parent. We've been tracking the issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/26), and you can find a few work-arounds in that thread. Basically, if you use the fallback class (before Sass 3.3), you have to nest `at-breakpoint` inside another selector. In most cases (including yours) that's a simple as moving the mixin inside your existing selectors:

```
.l-header,
.l-main,
.l-footer,
.l-region--navigation {
  @include at-breakpoint($desk) {
    @include set-container-width;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric, wouldn't have been able to find this on my own.